# Mongo - How to query by category

Tags: mongodb

I have the need to list links on a page, grouped together by category.

In MySql this would be easy - I'd have a category table and a links table. The Links table would include a category Id. I could then loop over the entries in the category table and 
query the the links table where category matches the current category.

I've been reading about model tree structures in Mongo and things seem to work a little differently ([link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/)). The basic list seems to be either store a parent or child reference in the document directly which allows you to 
create a tree strcuture. I'm unsure how to use these sort of structures to output the data as I need it. I need to somehow loop over the categories and then query the links based on that.

I'm wondering if I can just take the same approach as I would have with Sql? So have a seperate categories collection and then in the links collection just have an object Id that points to the categories? I can then loop over categories and query the links table each time for all links with a matching category.

Comment: @Begueradj - Please don't edit my post so it no longer makes sense!

Comment: I do not think I changed the meaning of your post. For example *I have the need to* is equivalent to *I need* (the less you write, the better you help the reader)

Comment: you can do it the same way as in sql but why do you need a separate categories table?  why not include the category in links?  btw, can each link have more than one category?  your described sql schema wouldn't be able to accommodate that.

Comment: btw, I don't see why you need to query categories, you can just query links grouping them by categories (using aggregation framework).

Comment: @Beguaeradj - you changed it to "I to list have the need to list" - which makes no sense

Comment: @aysa Kamsky - how do i query by category if it's all in the same collection? Order by category or something? I need to output a heading for each category also. And yes, links can have more than one category